# How to run Swift binaries compiled on macOS on Linux?

Tags: swift, linux, xcode, debian

So I have a Command Line application here in Xcode on my Mac and I can get the build binary and run it. 
Is it possible to run that binary on Linux or somehow build the project to run on Linux?
I'm using Virtual Box with Debian Linux 10.2, Xcode 11.2.1, macOS 10.15.1

Comment: Did you check these? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44300628/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48242496/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/35041483/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45595057/1187415,

Comment: Thanks! I guess I should've made Swift Package Manager project, not command line app in Xcode