# A Swift project inside another Swift project. add import module of the sub project

Tags: ios, swift, setup-project, subproject

I have added Project B into Project A as sub project. Directly drag and dropped to the Project A. I have some classes in Project B like Class X, Class Y. 
    I need to access these Project B classes Class X, Y in project A. When I directly use the classes, Im getting Class not found error.
  When I tried to add Project B name as Mobule name,Im getting Module not found error. 
   Same can work in Objective C , by giving #import "ClassX.h". But how to do it in Swift project?

Comment: I think you would do better with a bit of refactoring - create a Framework target. See my detailed answer on doing this in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41207622/how-to-make-same-ios-swift-app-with-only-some-differences-in-the-code-and-assets/41209283#41209283

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1 :** Click on that Swift file.

**Step 2** : Go to `File Inspector` (First tab in right panel)

**Step 3 :** Tick on all required targets (This will give you access of that file to all ticked targets)

**Step 4 :** Enjoy :)

[image: Tick on target]

Else,

**Step 1 :** Click on SubProject on which you want to add that file `ClassX`.

**Step 2 :** Go to it's `Build Phases` (6th tab)

**Step 3 :** Click on `+` under `Compiler Sources`

**Step 4 :** Click Add Other...

**Step 5 :** Choose file `ClassX` and finish.

Comment: The targets are shown only for Project B, it is not showing Project A target.  Without adding targets, can we do it. Like adding Imports?

Comment: @bharathgangupalli please refer update answer's else section.

Comment: Thanks Zaid. But I need it to be loosely coupled. I should be easily move the sub project to different repository. So, I can't add the dependencies. For eg. In Objective C, we can do #import "ClassX.h" in parent project to use the class. Similarly can we have for Swift?

Comment: @bharathgangupalli If you want to make that `ClassX` independent of both projects then you could make framework of it and then import that framework in both projects whenever needed. (Note : This will save your compile time).
Sorry but I did not understand your last statement.

Comment: ClassX belongs to Project B which is a Sub project. I added this sub project (Project B) to Project A. Now I need to access Class X from Project A. (Class X is part of Project B)

Comment: Yes so the approach described in Else part could be used or your could make Framework as described earlier.
Without linking `ClassX` to your target you can not get access of it within code.