# iOS import custom framework into project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

I've developped a framework which I want to use in my projects. Everything went right until I tried to build my project. Here the error description :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:  
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ClassInFramework", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ClassInMyProject.o  
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

My Architectures build settings are :

```
$(ARCHS_STANDARD)
```

and `arm64 armv7 armv7s` for valid arch
(same settings in my project and my framework, there are all default settings)

I can `import myframework` and build with no issue, but I get that error when I tried to use a class.

I'm on XCode 8.2.1, my Framework is a Cococa touch Framework, written in Objective-C, my project is written in Swift 3.0

I imported my framework by copying the output from Products and added it in Linked Frameworks and Libraries in my project

I've tried several different settings but none of them work.

Comment: I add my frameworks differently (and they are all in Swift), so this may be useless. Is the framework added to "Embedded Binaries" in your project?

Comment: No it was not added by default, I tried to add but same error.

Comment: Did you build the framework for the simulator and are running the project on a device? The architecture for a device is different than for a simulator

Comment: You might find your answer somewhat (but I'm not sure) similair to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634466/how-to-export-fat-cocoa-touch-framework-for-simulator-and-device

Comment: I built both on devices or simulators, but still get the same errors. Maybe I'm not importing in the right way?

Comment: This is a two year old question with answers addressing bridging headers. Hopefully this isn't outdated and of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057756/import-framework-in-swift-project-xcode?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunatly same error with a bridging header :(

Comment: That's all I have. I think it's related to the mix of Obj-C and Swift. Having said that, here's an answer on how I import my framework into a project (specifically, item #2). Keep in mind, this is two separate project (both Swift) that are obviously two frameworks. Maybe it'll work for you. My last chance at helping.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41207622/how-to-make-same-ios-swift-app-with-only-some-differences-in-the-code-and-assets/41209283#41209283

Comment: Well, thanks for your answers and help. I think i will do something similar to your answer.

Comment: If it does, could you post something? I'd like to know that mixing Obj-C and Swift this way works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solve my issue but I've managed to do something similar.
Instead of creating a Cocoa touch framework I created a Cocoa Touch static library and it worked.

1. I build my library,
2. I get the products (*.h and .a files), copy them in my project,
3. I add the lib.a in Linked Frameworks and libraries,
4. I create the Bridging Header and #import my "customlib.h",
5. Magic ! It works I can use my class.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove  the project folder from Xcode Drived Date and restart your Xcode then clean your project and run it.

Comment: I'm stil getting the same error :(. I even tried recreate the project, reimport, still getting the error.